# Android Emulator Freeze on OS X Yosmitee

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, crash, freeze

I've updated my OS X to Yosemite, but now the Android emulator freezes.
I'm getting the following error:

> > Process:               emulator64-x86 [1339] Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/emulator64-x86 Identifier:            emulator64-x86
> >     Version:               ??? Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
> >     Parent Process:        eclipse [1287] Responsible:           eclipse
> >     [1287] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2014-10-19 10:57:48.980 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   27F3D44F-A72F-BA50-C0CE-0DB00AF85DDD
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 3400 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS) Exception Codes:
>   0x000000000000000a, 0x000000010809d536
>
> VM Regions Near 0x10809d536:
>   --> __TEXT                 0000000107ee0000-0000000108122000 [ 2312K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Volumes/VOLUME/*
>       __DATA                 0000000108122000-0000000108571000 [ 4412K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  /Volumes/VOLUME/*
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   emulator64-x86                    0x0000000107f801fd
>   tcg_add_target_add_op_defs + 109 1   emulator64-x86
>     0x0000000107fa92e0 cpu_gen_init + 16 2   emulator64-x86
>     0x0000000107fa52e9 cpu_exec_init_all + 9 3   emulator64-x86
>     0x0000000107eefee0 qemu_main + 4784 4   emulator64-x86
>     0x0000000107efb676 SDL_main + 6134 5   emulator64-x86
>     0x000000010806ffa0 QZ_InitOSKeymap + 3168 6
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8fb92cbc
>   **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12 7   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8fa841b4 _CFXNotificationPost
>   + 3140 8   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff92413ea1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66 9   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8ba6925b -[NSApplication
>   _postDidFinishNotification] + 291 10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ba68fc6 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification]
>   + 191 11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ba65dc6 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 574 12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ba65805
>   -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 244 13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92433458 -[NSAppleEventManager
>   dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290 14 
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff924332c9
>   _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102 15  com.apple.AE                     0x00007fff9174399c aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*,
>   unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 531 16  com.apple.AE
>     0x00007fff91743719 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*)
>   + 31 17  com.apple.AE                     0x00007fff91743623 aeProcessAppleEvent + 295 18  com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff8ac1437e AEProcessAppleEvent + 56 19  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fff8ba61ec6 _DPSNextEvent + 2665 20  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fff8ba60fd0 -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194 21 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8ba54f73 -[NSApplication run]
>   + 594 22  emulator64-x86                  0x0000000108070647 main + 1351 23  emulator64-x86                   0x0000000107ee5584 start + 52
>
> Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8b9fe22e kevent64 + 10 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff87e9ea6a _dispatch_mgr_thread
>   + 52
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b9fd946
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8ee184a1 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b9fd946
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8ee184a1 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b9fd946
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8ee184a1 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b9fd946
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8ee184a1 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b9fd946
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8ee184a1 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x00007f91b283a608  rbx: 0x00000001081266e0  rcx: 0x0000000108127230 
>   rdx: 0x000000010809d536   rdi: 0x0000000108127080  rsi:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000108151070  rsp: 0x00007fff57d1d560
>   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10:
>   0x0000000000000001  r11: 0x00000000fdc458a9   r12: 0x0000000107f8030c 
>   r13: 0x00000001081265e0  r14: 0x00007fff57d1de30  r15:
>   0x0000000000000000   rip: 0x0000000107f801fd  rfl: 0x0000000000010246 
>   cr2: 0x000000010809d536    Logical CPU:     1 Error Code:
>   0x00000004 Trap Number:     14